# Samba with LDAP queries the wrong sambaDomainName

Tags: ubuntu, ldap, samba

I've set up Samba on Ubuntu use LDAP, but it insists on using the host name for the `sambaDomainName` query, instead of the configured workgroup, and so it fails to get the domain info.

If I set `netbios name` to the workgroup name, then it works, but then the server shows up on the network with the workgroup name instead of the host name, which is not what I want.

I can query LDAP using `ldapsearch` with the right `sambaDomainName`, so I'm pretty sure that part is good.

I'm using Samba 2:4.7.6+dfsg~ubuntu-0ubuntu2.2

Partial config:

```
[global]
    security = domain
    passdb backend = ldapsam:"ldap://ldap-server"
    workgroup = MYGROUP
    netbios name = HOSTNAME
```

I've tried with `security=user`, and `server role = standalone` but they make no difference. I don't have a Windows domain, just a workgroup and an LDAP server provided by JumpCloud (They have the Samba schema configured, and it works for all my other non-Samba LDAP clients).

Regardless of how I configure this I know I have other things to finish with the actual idmap setup, but AFAIK it won't make any difference unless it can properly query LDAP in the first place, thus the partial config above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The missing config entries, which I found after digging through the samba source code, where:

`[global]
    security = user
    domain logons = yes`

That will make it use the `workgroup` config entry instead of the `netbios name`. Internally this is determined based on a combination of the `security`, `domain logons`, and `server role` settings. `server role` can be omitted from the config as the default will be valid with the two settings above.

Comment: Brilliant - thank you, very helpful.
We also had the server role set to standalone server. Commented this out: # server role = standalone server and the samba server is now obeying the WORKGROUP setting.